# Will Deore M6000 SGS derailleur work with 42t cassette in 1x10 configuration?

Tags: drivetrain

I'm building a 26er 1x10 commuter. I have a 40t chainring and 11-42 cassette.

Will an out-of-the-box (no goat link or extra-long B screw) 2017 Deore M6000 SGS Rear Derailleur work with this?

Will the YBN SLA 101-TiB chain have enough links to cover the drivetrain?

Comment: If you look at Shimano's website they say that the Deore M6000 SGS is for a maximum sprocket of 36t.

Comment: You might want to try the SRAM Rival/Apex 1 group. It's pretty close to what you want (10-42 cassette, 40t chainrings available; its a 11 speed group though). You can use the RD with a 10 speed SRAM shifter, so you can get a 10 speed cassette, the Rival/Apex 1 RD, SRAM 10 speed shifter and the 1x crankset to do what you want.

Comment: @Carel, that's a safe number that also includes full suspension chain growth issued by manufacturer. Anecdotal evidence shows that on hardtail you can add a couple of teeth to that (i.e. RD-M640 FR and 40 teeth cog).

Comment: @JM C. I'd look at RD-M7000 as an option, it will work relatively OK with 10 speed cassette and has different geometry out of the box to support big range cassettes. I run RD-M9000 GS over 10 speed 11-36 and it shifts OK after some fine tension tuning.

Comment: *SGS* version med cage - max 36t sprocket, *GS* version long cage - max 42t sprocket  according to Shimano. However, If GS and SGS geometry only differ in cage length, I don't know why the SGS could not be used with a 42 tooth sprocket in a 1x setup. Can anybody shed light on that?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - SS = short cage, GS = medium, SGS = long. I'm not sure why the data sheets say that the SGS has a different max tooth than the GS; I suspect it might have to do with the body angle and cage length coupling, if its not a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda just assumed longer cage = more capacity

Comment: @Klaster_1: Well, Shimano always try to be on the safe side, probably because of liability. A 42t sprocket may well work with said derailleur. Likewise they say that a 52-34 chainring combination should not be used but I have been using it on my road-bike for three months now without any problems.

Comment: @Carel: It's confusing because the SGS is supposed to be long cage and GS the medium cage (and the GS is the one listed with the max sprocket capacity of 42T). Reading up online, most users and vendors advised getting a long cage for the Sunrace MS3 because of its range.

Batman: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, SRAM components are pretty hard to come by in my neck of the woods, and when they do come up, are often more expensive compared to their Shimano counterparts.

Comment: @Klaster_1That's one of my options, an M6000 shifter paired with an 11s M7000. Saw a lot of people with that setup (or m8000 RD) and it seemed to work well for them. 
<br>

Comment: However, seems I found my answer today. Was looking for people who have already tinkered with the combination, and found Orbea had a bike with almost the same drivetrain setup as the one in my head. They used an M6000 GS RD with a Sunrace 11-42 with a 42T chain wheel

[Orbea Gain F10](https://www.orbea.com/gb-en/ebikes/gain-f10)

Answer (score 10):

I talked to Shimano this morning and got the final word. The reason the long cage  is designated as having a shorter reach than the medium cage is because the long cages is designed to be used with the triple crankset.  The Shimano  representative  I spoke with confirmed that the long cage is indeed only designed to wrap around 36T cog.
The bottom line is the medium cage m6000 derailleur  is the only 10 speed derailleur designed to work with the 11-42t cassette out of the box.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE.  When you have further information on this combo, please come back and used the "edit" link under your answer to flesh it out with more detail.  As you may have noticed, this isn't a chatty web forum, instead its a Question and Answers format.  And thank you for answering a question that had nothing before.

Comment: Thanks for the newbie advise. I hope my edit is more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very late but here's my experience with my 26" commuter bike, actually I converted it for summer touring because during the rest of the year I commute with 42 front and 12-25 rear

M6000 SGS (designed for 36 max) can work with 42 but you need a longer M5 screw, that's the quickest and cheapest solution, now I'm using 34 single ring front, 11-42 HG500 cassette, also the previous SLX derailler is fine with a rear 42.

Answer (score 2):

I just converted my 26er from 3x7 to 1x10 (32x11-42) and it works fine with Deore M6000 SGS. Tried both attaching the derailleur with/without an extension, surprisingly it works better without.

Answer (score 1):

I am even later and had exactly the same question/issue. I have the RD-M6000-SGS and the 11-42 HG500 cassette.

When I put the height setting bolt full in I believe it's maybe just ok. But to have a bit more range I changed the original bolt, M4 x 18 (note, it's M4, not M5!) to a headless M4 x 20mm.

Note that the original Shimano bolt has a small head (~ Ø5.3mm), typical is 6.9mm. Since the RD has a cavity for the head a normal size bolt will not fit. You need to go either longer, M4 x 25 or go headless.

My headless type is [DIN 913](https://www.fasteners.eu/standards/DIN/913/) but ideal would be a headless bolt with dog point [DIN 915](https://www.fasteners.eu/standards/DIN/915/)